# best possible algorithm for finding out an ordering $i_1i_2..i_n$ such that $b_{i_k}=a_{i_k+1}$ for $k=1$ to $n-1$

Tags: algorithms

Suppose that I have a given set of items $S$. Now I have been given $n$ sequences made using the items in $S$ like
$$a_1(...)b_1, a_2(...)b_2,...a_n(...)b_n$$
The sequences have lengths
$$l_1,l_2,...l_n$$
The internal items don't matter for this question, hence I've put them in $(...)$. I have to find if an ordering of the sequence of these $n$ sequences exists (let that ordering be $i_1,i_2,...i_n$) satisfying 
$$b_{i_k}=a_{i_{k+1}}$$
for $k=1,2,...n-1$. So, $a_{i_1},b_{i_n}$ can be anything in $S$ but the ordering assumes the above condition. Just to make it even clearer, suppose $S=<1,2,3>$ and the sequences $(n=3)$ are
$$122,223,322$$
A solution would be then $<1,2,3>$ since $122-223-322$ satisfies the condition. My question is, what is the best possible algorithm to find if such an ordering exists?

Comment: You use integers in your example, but in reality are the elements of $S$ sortable? This probably affects the answer a lot.

Comment: Yeah, they are sortable.

Comment: I can think of an algorithm that has *worst case* $O(N^2\log N)$ complexity but I have no feel for the amortized result (maybe you're only interested in worst case?). Also it's pretty brute force so there're probably cleverer ways.

Comment: Never mind, write an answer. I'm trying to find out ways to solve this kind of problem, so any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, best case here is $O(N\log N)$.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple (pretty much brute force) algorithm. First store the sequences in a binary tree based upon the sorting order of the first element of the sequence (for example [C++'s std map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)) this allows us $O(\log N)$ access to the sequences.

For sequence $i$ get the value of the last element of the sequence and use its value $b_i$ to search the tree for a sequence $j$ beginning with $b_i$ - $O(\log N)$. Repeat for sequence $j$, until you have arranged all sequences in order - $O(N)$.

If we do not find a next sequence $j$ we know this chain does not work so go back to the beginning and choose the next starting sequence. In the worst case the last sequence we look at forms the chain (or there is no such chain) - $O(N)$.

These are just thoughts, I haven't written or tested it. Also we're assuming that access to the last element of the sequences is always possible in constant $O(1)$ time since we know their lengths $l_i$.

Comment: Why is the best case $O(N\log N)$? Shouldn't it be $O(N)$, i.e. the time taken for the input?

Comment: No because the sequence of sequences will be $N$ sequences long, but for each element we have a look up, which is $O(\log N)$ therefore if we hit the/a valid chain on the first go we still have $O(N\cdot \log N)$.

Comment: That is, using a map in C++, right? If we used a hash table with constant lookup, it would be $O(N)$.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah I suppose that would also work, then the worst case becomes $O(N^2)$ and best case is $O(N)$.